# How can I get the world grid and backdrop grid to be visible in a render?

Tags: rendering

I have tried to find the answer to this question in the blender manual and in various forum but have not had any luck.

What I want to do is to make the world grid and the backdrop grid (orthographic view) visible in the final render. I do not wish to create a grid from the add mesh button since they do not look the same as the world grids.

Is this even possible?
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Nay if you want to see a grid in your scene you have to add a grid...What makes the mesh look different from the world grid anyway ? Use a wireframe texture for rendering and you wil be able to control the thickness of the edges and their color...

Comment: Welcome fivefootnine :)  Does [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41499/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-vertical-grid-show-on-final-image-rendered) help? If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help) and start with the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour). Anyway, enjoy blender.se!

Comment: @poor It states in the question that he would not like to use a mesh as he requires the grid to look the same.

Comment: Thanks for the replys. yvain said that I can use a wireframe texture for rendering to be able to control the thickness of edges etc. This does not solve my problem since I want to render in solid mode? The backdrop grid is a feature that is built in in blender. Is that feauture impossible to incorporate in the render? Maybe with a script?

Comment: Not that I know of. Even with a script the best the script would do is add the mesh and colour it for you. You need to add some sort of image or geometry if it is to show up in the render. And when you say solid mode do you mean the way the view port is rendered? If so you can change the view port colour of a mesh in the material settings. You could use this to create a grid, although you would have to do some work if it is to look the same as the grid in blender. If you don't mind adding an image as long as it looks the same, look at my answer below.

Comment: @SchoolBoy Good point. I appreciate your answer, but I think using geometry can look the same (since it's a simple OpenGL drawing) and let you stay in blender as well. The best solution is probably a [bgl script](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/912/draw-geometry-on-screen-using-bgl-module) to achieve the same result or style, but writing solid code would take too much time for this too vague question (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is **not possible using the standard render methods**.

**However**, one way you can add it is by capturing an image of the grid as a screen shot from top orthographic view after hiding all visible objects. The grey background can then be removed using an image editing program and added to the scene as so:

Grid image (you are free to use this one if you like):
[image: Grid]

Then create a plane exactly the size of this image (6x6) and UV unwrap the plane

**Cycles:**

Set the material to the following node setup:
[image: Node setup]

This makes the material only visible to the camera and transparent where there is no grid.

This can then be used in your renders :)

**Blender internal:**

For blender render simply enable Z-transparency in the materials and set the alpha to 0. Also enable shadeless and disable cast shadow.

[image: Shadeless and transparent]
[image: no shadow]

Then select the image in the textures tab. Then ensure that the texture affects the alpha of the material by turning up alpha (just under color) to 1.

[image: influence alpha]

If the grid is too thick you can scroll up to image sampling, disable MIP map and lower the filter size. This should make the grid thinner.

You can now use it in your renders :)

[image: Cycles render]
[image: BI render]

[image]

Comment: There's no need to remove grey color of the scene from the screenshot from top ortho view; change world background to the full white in World Settings and choose it to be shown in the *Toolshelf*.

Comment: @MrZak But then you'd have to remove the white anyway since a transparent image is needed.

Comment: Probably (I thought about OpenGL render viewport but don't think it's option now). Either way this method will be less accurate because it involves taking screenshot and editing image; it would be more flexible to create several curves with *Vector* type handles and setup them appropriately (covered in the linked answer); optionally bake result into image.

Comment: @MrZak I know that it might be more flexible, but then more work is required to get it to look the same. This to me seems like a really quick solution. And yes, OpenGL render is available but it does not render the grid. This is what I originally tried too, I thought it could simply be rendered out for as big of a grid as required. And in fact, I don't think it will be inaccurate because even if it is an image, the grid when taken a screen shot of is exactly one pixel. And as long as the plane being used is the same size as the grid it will fit perfectly to scale.

Comment: @SchoolBoy ... you stated ... [a really quick solution].  I would say you have really quick sufficient solution.  ¡ Bravo !.  You may be  helping other readers.  You may help the original poser of the question.  You may help yourself.  Any combination is fine.  You do not need to fulfill or agree with the validity of every aspect of a question. Having different answers is good.  Many questions go unanswered here.  Other people can leave an alternative answer.

Comment: Yes I know, I also agree with the fact that having different answers is good. I just went for the approach of trying to achieve every aspect of the question. Like you say, other people can leave alternative answers. For some reason, it seems to me like you are trying to say that I was forcing this answer onto people. I am sorry if I sounded like that but I was merely discussing it and in no way did I mean that any other suggestions were wrong.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for providing help and especially Schoolboy for the detailed answer and file attachments! I do think there should be possible to render the grids in a future version of blender without all the hassle it takes now.